# Why gray color of folder in git?

Tags: git, github, yii2, phpstorm

I first time use Git. I use PhpStorm as IDE
When I commit a project or even recreate and commit
the 'basic' folder is gray.
And in PHP Storm it's also have a different color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a git submodule dir or something like that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

perhaps :

- PSR-O automatically detection and colors
- you work a new project with code other project
- wrong config git for your project
- color PHPStorm for notice you that change anything
- what the 'change view' PHPStorm notice ?
- How many .git directory are you in a project ?
- Are you modify the color config for anything into PHPStorm ?
- Plugins behaviour ?